# Finding the eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I was trying to prove the following theorem and got stuck at one point :

Theorem :

Let $A\in M_n(F)$, then the scalar $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if
$$
det(A-\lambda*I_n) = 0.
$$

Proof:

I started off like this ,

A scalar $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if there exists a non zero vector $v\in F^n$ such that $Av = \lambda v$.
$$
\Rightarrow (A-\lambda I_n)(v) = 0
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow (A-\lambda I_n) \text{ is not invertible}
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow det (A-\lambda I_n) = 0
$$
I figured that $(A - \lambda I_n)$ should not be invertible to get the det as $0$ , but i don't really understand why it can't be invertible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is not invertible if and only if there exists $v\neq 0$ such that $Av=0$.

To be more precise: if $Av=0$ for some $v\neq 0$ then $A$ cannot be invertible since it is not injective: $Av=A0$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A - \lambda I$ was invertible, then we would have $(A - \lambda I)v = 0 \implies v = (A - \lambda I)^{-1}0 \implies v = 0$. But our assumption was $v \neq 0$, so $A - \lambda I$ must be non invertible.

Answer (score 1):

By definition, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ if and only if there exists a non-zero vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$.

This is equivalent to saying that $x \in \mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda \mathrm{I}_{n})$ or that $\mathrm{ker}(A-\lambda \mathrm{I}_{n}) \neq \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Remember that a matrix $M \in \mathcal{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is invertible if and only if $\det(M) \neq 0$ (also if and only if $\ker{M} = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$).

Answer (score 0):

Problems of that kind won't arise if you put the definitions on the right order.  Define *first* what an eigenvalue should be: 
$$\lambda \text{ is eigenvalue of $A$ }\iff\det(A-\lambda I)=0.$$

Now iff $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ we know that the eigenspace of  $A$ in respect to $\lambda$, namely $\operatorname{E}_{\lambda}=\ker(A-\lambda I)\neq \{0\}$.  Call *then* -- and not before! -- any vector in $\operatorname{E}_{\lambda}\setminus\{0\}$ an eigenvector of $A$ in respect to $\lambda$.