# Definition of eigen space.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, definition

I am studying linear algebra and got confused in defining eigen space corresponding to eigen value.The thing wondering me is the same thing defined in two different books in different manners.let $\lambda$ be eigen value of matrix $A$ of order n over the field $\mathbb{F}$ then Hoffman & kunze defines eigen space as follows:

> *Definition*:The collection of all $x\in\mathbb{F^n}$ such that $Ax=\lambda x$ is called the eigenspace associated with $\lambda$.

While in another book *A first course in module theory* by M.E Keating,he defines eigenspace as follows:

> *Definition*:Given an n x n matrix $A$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$, an eigenspace for $A$ is a nonzero 
>   subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{F^n}$ with the property that $$Ax=\lambda x$$ $\forall x\in U$

I think the two definitions are not equivalent:

> Let $x_1,x_2$ be two linearly independent eigenvectors corresponding to eigen value $\lambda$,then according to first definition a subspace generated by $x_1,x_2$ is the eigen space of $A$ corresponding to eigen value $\lambda$ while according to definition-2 there are three eigen space each of which generated by
>   (1)$x_1$ only,
>   (2)$x_2$ only,
>   (3) $x_1$ and $x_2$

Am I right in my understanding?since my graduation days I am familiar with first definition and used it in my problems,could anybody help me in understanding
Thanks in advance

Comment: You are correct that these definitions are different. The first one gives a unique set (note that it calls it *the* eigenspace) whereas the second one leaves a number of possibilities (note it's called *an* eigenspace). The eigenspace in the first definition is the maximal eigenspace of all those in the second definition. I can't speak to why the definitions are different, but in my experience the first one is more common. I wouldn't let it bother you too much though, sometimes people just define things differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/515689/finding-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix/515718#515718.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: they are not equivalent. The first definition is the usual one. The second one is more general: if $F_\lambda$ is the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda$ (with respect to the first definition), then the author of the second definition is saying that *any* non-zero subspace of $F_\lambda$ is *an* eigenspace for $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: Non-zero subspace. Not _any_ subspace.

Comment: @Somos I've edited my answer. Thank you.